# Scala works poorly with package objects with Unicode (non-ASCII) file names

Tags: scala, unicode

Using Scala 2.12.0-M3 under SBT / Windows 10, I expect this code to compile and print "1" but Scala complains about not finding a variable under a package object with a non-ASCII name.

(1)

```
package パッケージ
package object パッケージ {
  val a = 1
}
```

(2)

```
package second
import パッケージ._
object Example extends App {
  println(a)
}
```

Is this a bug in the compiler? Can anyone else reproduce this issue on another platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks correct that this code doesn't compile.

When you declare a package object X in a package Y, it means that X resides in Y.

```
println(パッケージ.a)
```

would work. To make it clear, a rewritten version of your second source:

```
package second
object Example extends App {
  println(パッケージ.パッケージ.a)
}
```

Now suppose you have package `x` and we'd want to create a package object `y`, whose fully qualified name is `x.y`, in other words that object would reside **inside** `x`:

```
package x
package object y
```

Now from the "root" package if we want to refer to `y` we'd need to either `import x` or use it's fully qualified name `x.y`.

Your original code is slightly confusing because you have **two** packages with the **same name**, one **inside** the other, and the inner one happens to be a package object.

Comment: Variables in package objects are supposed to be accessible without qualification if the package is imported, though. In fact, if you replace `パッケージ` with `pkg`, the code should and does compile.

Comment: I believe that what @pedrofurla is saying, correctly, is that you have a package object one level too far down, basically if you have `package a.b.c` and you want to create a package object for c its declaration should be `package a.b` followed by `package object c`. see the examples at http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html. An alternative fix would be to remove the line starting with `package` from your first file.

Comment: @bb94, which package did you rename to `pkg` and compiled? the package alone or the package object? Don't see how either case would compile.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!